# Resign ipa and submit it to Apple

Tags: xcode, ipa

Is there a way to resign an ipa took from another developer and submit it to apple?

**Update**
After fastlane released it's a piece of cake. See here https://github.com/fastlane/sigh#resign

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible to resign an ipa.

As Alexspott mentions you will need to have an Apple Developers Account, have created an AppID that matches the ipa's bundle ID (If you aren't able to register the App ID to match the bundle ID exactly, you could use a wildcard app ID as long as your app isn't using Push Notifications or In App Purchases), have a valid Certificate, and generate a provisioning profile for this App ID and Certificate.

Make sure that you have this Certificate in your keychain.

To resign the ipa go through the following steps in Terminal:

$ cd *path/where/the/ipa/file/is/*

$ unzip *original*.ipa

$ rm -rf /Payload/*theapp*.app/_CodeSignature/

$ cp *YourProvisioningProfile*.mobileprovision Payload/*theapp*.app/embedded.mobileprovision

$ codesign -f -s "*YourCertificateName*” Payload/*theapp*.app

$ zip -qr *resigned*.ipa Payload/

This can be a bit of a pain, and it's something that I have to do fairly often, so I've made a script to simplify the process.  For example, instead of writing all of the above, you would just write:

$ ipaHelper resign *original*.ipa -p *YourProvisioningProfile*.mobileprovision

Its also handles issues that occasionally pop up with Entitlements.  If you're interested I have the source code on github:

https://github.com/MarcusSmith/ipaHelper

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the source to resign the app. But you have to have Apple Developers Account and  create AppID, AppStore provisioning profile e.t.c. Basically perform all the steps for publishing to the AppStore.

Take a look on [www.aironapp.com](http://www.aironapp.com), it provides resigning functionality plus it can submit to the AppStore for you.